# Can I insert data in batch with Mybatis in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

Can I insert data in batch with Mybatis in DolphinDB?

Is there a function like “foreach” to insert data in batch with Mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use Java API to insert data in batches. You can configure JDBC to connect to DolphinDB on Mybatis.